# Files in a bind-mounted folder seem to disappear after Docker container exits

Tags: docker, docker-compose, node-modules

I am working with docker-compose and I am trying to understand how I should configure my `node_modules` folder. I am having trouble understanding how files are persisted with either volumes or bind-mounts in Docker. Here's my project set up:

```
user@computer:~/myprojects/deleteme$ tree
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── frontend
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── package.json
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app/frontend
    container_name: frontend
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /app/frontend

RUN npm install

RUN echo "Node done!"
RUN touch foo
RUN ls
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "deleteme",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git"
  },
  "scripts": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-datetime": "2.16.3",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-router": "5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }
}
```

When I do `docker-compose build --no-cache`, I get

```
Building frontend
Step 1/6 : FROM node:12-alpine
 ---> 057fa4cc38c2
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /app/frontend
 ---> Running in 81229692051b
Removing intermediate container 81229692051b
 ---> 0ef46ff4472d
Step 3/6 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in cf7afc9d1f54
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/frontend/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/frontend/package.json'
npm WARN frontend No description
npm WARN frontend No repository field.
npm WARN frontend No README data
npm WARN frontend No license field.

up to date in 0.227s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Removing intermediate container cf7afc9d1f54
 ---> af6169ff583b
Step 4/6 : RUN echo "Node done!"
 ---> Running in e037c7bbd127
Node done!
Removing intermediate container e037c7bbd127
 ---> 843945701b93
Step 5/6 : RUN touch foo
 ---> Running in fc0663e95e48
Removing intermediate container fc0663e95e48
 ---> 48460f061742
Step 6/6 : RUN ls
 ---> Running in 594b7843bc8b
foo
package-lock.json
Removing intermediate container 594b7843bc8b
 ---> 6d4e09b0ff64
Successfully built 6d4e09b0ff64
Successfully tagged deleteme_frontend:latest
```

I don't understand why `package.json` is not already in the container's `/app/frontend` since I specified `./frontend:/app/frontend` in `docker-compose.yml`. And I don't understand why `foo` and `package-lock.json` seam to disappear once the container exists because, if I do `tree` again, I get

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── frontend
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── package.json
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because **volumes are mounted only when the container is running**, not when the image is built. You need to use `COPY` command in the `Dockerfile` to add files from `./frontend` on the build stage. Example:

```
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /app/frontend
COPY frontend ./
RUN npm install
```

Comment: Is there any way to just mount the whole directory instead of doing copies?

Comment: There is no way to mount a volume during build of `Dockerfile`. One of the reasons -- when image is built, everything related to build must be persisted to image FS. Otherwise, the container might be unusable after the start. See [official Docker Hub of Python](https://hub.docker.com/_/python), for example of `COPY . .`. There are volume usage too, but only for scripts **without** external dependencies (std lib only). Sorry for Python example, [Node.JS Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) is not explaining this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You are mounting files to container runtime obviously it will get deleted once container deleted. you have to add these files at build time(docker build) so that your application related files live along with image, so your dockerfile should be like this

```
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /app/frontend

COPY ./frontend ./          <<---- here

RUN npm install

RUN echo "Node done!"
RUN touch foo
RUN ls
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know that mounts are done at runtime and not during build time. This explains why `package.json` was not available to the `Dockerfile`. Does this explain why `foo` was gone though -- so the `Dockerfile` does a touch into a directory that is not yet mounted so `./frontend:/app/frontend` actually overwrites `foo`?